# How to use models in codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am very new to the codeigniter-3 framework,i am using models in controller like this `$this->load->model('model_name')` it's working fine ,i am trying to use following way but it's throwing an error can you please help me to fix this issue

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Error

Message: Class 'models\TestModel' not found
```

`TestController.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use \models\TestModel;

class TestController extends CI_Controller {

    public function student(){
        $obj = new TestModel();
        $value = $obj->student_college();
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class TestController extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // Load model
        $this->load->model('TestModel');
    }
    public function student(){
        $obj = new TestModel();
        $value = $obj->student_college();
        echo $value;
    }
}
```